# How to override an existing pipe

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I'm using ngx-translate in my component like so:

```
{{ 'TRANSLATE_THIS' | translate }}
```

I would like to override this translate pipe's transformation function with a function provided by the parent component through `@Input()`, I do not want to modify the HTML template due to a specific need. Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: Have you tried adding the type to the decorator on the component? `@Component({ providers: [YourCustomPipeType ]`} ? I am not sure exactly what you mean by `with a function provided by the parent component through @Input()` though.

Comment: Thanks, @Igor 
I would like to replace only the transformation function provided by the PipeTransform, without registering a new pipe to angular. Is that possible / does that make any sense?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to register the "custom" pipe at the component level (not globally)? That can be done, see my 1st comment. If that is not what you meant then I am still unclear as to what you are asking or how you envision it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply override the pipe by using the same `name` for defining the pipe.

See example [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-override-pipe)

Edit: If you want to pass anything to the pipe for customization, you can simply use the parameters. Check the updated code.

Comment: I tried that, that works. But I'm not sure if I have multiple pipes of same name which one will get the priority? / Also, is it possible to replace only the transform function, without registering a new pipe?

Comment: The order of imports will matter here. Updated example with a custom module which exports a pipe. Try changing the order of `BrowserModule` and the `CustomModule`.

Comment: What if the custom pipe is defined in the host app module and not in a submodule. How can I set the priority?

Comment: The one declared in the module will be considered in that case. It also depends where the component is declared in which you are trying to use the pipe.